# $μ_t$ becomes SubscriptBox[\[Mu], t]

Tags: formatting, mathematica-online, subscript, format

I was using variables like **$μ_t$** in my **local** Mathematica notebook. But when I opened that notebook in Mathematica Online everything got converted to something like **SubscriptBox[[Mu], t]**.

How can retain the **$μ_t$** like format in the Online Mathematica notebook?

Comment: What version of **local** Mathematica are you using?

Comment: You'd be better off contacting Wolfram about this, but when I investigated similar claims I believe they told me that linear syntax was not yet officially supported... A shame because the documentation doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @QuantumDot, I am using 11.0.0.0

Comment: @user6014 what does "linear syntax" mean?